# SQLFluff always returns templating/parsing errors

Tags: python, sql, sqlfluff

I am trying to set up sqlfluff but for all of our queries it always returns this when running `sqlfluff fix`

```
[1 templating/parsing errors found]
```

Is there any way how I can force it to tell me the error that occurs? I tried running it on highes verbosity level but no useful information logged.

Comment: There's no way to answer this question without seeing your SQL and your `.sqlfluff` config file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the command `sqlfluff parse`, which will give you the line numbers of where the parse violations are occurring. Once you've rectified all parse violations, run `sqlfluff fix` again.